# Selection of item in RecyclerView in NestedScrollView is causing the scrolling to jump

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a drawer layout which is a fragment.  The drawerlayout contains a NestedScrollView and in this nestedScrollView I have a recycler view with check boxes and radio buttons.  The problem is that when I make a selection on a checkbox or radio button, the recyclerview seems to scroll, causing the whole Nested View to scroll to a position above the bottom.

[image: video of what's happening]

I've done:

```
binding.recyclerview.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false;
```

and also in the recyclerview layout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants
```

Here is the layout of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/wpd_start_margin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/wpd_start_margin" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/wpd_end_margin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/wpd_end_margin" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/wpd_end_sortBy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/wpfd_wpd_end_sortBy" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/wpd_small_margin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/wpfd_wpd_small_margin" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/wpd_end_apply_filter_margin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/wpfd_wpd_end_apply_filter_margin" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/filterHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/wpfd_height_of_filter_row"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:elevation="@dimen/wpfd_elevation_filters"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                >
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/wpd_start_margin_elevated_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/wpd_start_margin" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/wpd_end_margin_elevated_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/wpd_end_margin" />
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/wpd_filter_guideline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/wpfd_wpd_filter_guideline" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/filter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/wpfd_height_of_filter_row"
                android:fontFamily="@font/graphikcompact_semibold"
                app:fontFamily="@font/graphikcompact_semibold"
                style="@style/HeadingStd600LaPrimaryGrey100"
                android:text="@string/work_package_filters_nav_header"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/wpd_start_margin_elevated_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:contentDescription="@string/work_package_drawer_close"
                android:id="@+id/close_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/wpfd_close_button_height_and_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/wpfd_close_button_height_and_width"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_close"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:tint="@color/bechtel_blue_80"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/wpd_filter_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/wpd_end_margin_elevated_view"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/filter"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.500" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/spinnerOutline"
                style="@style/SortByTextInputLayoutStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/work_package_drawer_sort_by"
                app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_icon_chevron_down"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/wpfd_sort_by_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/wpfd_sort_by_margin_start"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/wpfd_sort_by_margin_end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/wpfd_margin_bottom_ascend_descend"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/wpd_end_sortBy"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sortByBarrier"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filterHeader">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    tools:ignore="Deprecated,LabelFor" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:contentDescription="@string/work_package_drawer_ascend_descend"
                android:id="@+id/btnAscendDescend"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/wpfd_ascend_descend_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/wpfd_ascend_descend_size"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_sort"
                app:iconTint="@color/bechtel_blue_80"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/wpfd_asced_descend_margin_end"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/wpfd_margin_top_ascend_descend"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/wpfd_margin_bottom_ascend_descend"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                app:strokeColor="@color/grey_30"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinnerOutline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/filterHeader"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                 />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
                android:id="@+id/sortByBarrier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:barrierDirection="bottom"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="spinnerOutline,btnAscendDescend" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sortByBarrier"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                tools:listitem="@layout/workpackage_filter_nav_drawer_row_radio_button"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnResetFilters"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/wpfd_layout_height_reset_button"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/wpfd_reset_filters_margin_top"
                android:fontFamily="@font/graphikcompact"
                android:insetTop="0dp"
                android:insetBottom="0dp"
                android:text="@string/work_package_drawer_reset_all_filters"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:fontFamily="@font/graphikcompact_semibold"
                app:cornerRadius="@dimen/wpfd_corner_radius"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonCnd400CaPrimaryBechtelBlue"
                android:textColor="@color/material_button_text_selector"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/wpd_end_margin"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/wpd_start_margin"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerview"
                app:strokeColor="@color/bechtel_blue_80"
                app:strokeWidth="@dimen/wpfd_stroke_width" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bottomView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/wpfd_text_size_bottom_view_height"
                android:background="@color/bechtel_blue_80"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnResetFilters"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/wpfd_reset_filters_margin_top"/>

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/wpfd_bottom_buttons_margin_top"
                android:text="@string/work_package_drawer_cancel"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonCnd400LaPrimaryBechtelBlue"
                android:textColor="@color/bechtel_blue_80"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/wpfd_margin_end_close_button"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/button_white_color_states"
                app:fontFamily="@font/graphikcompact_semibold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnApplyFilters"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnResetFilters"
                 />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnApplyFilters"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/graphikcompact_semibold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ButtonCnd400LaPrimaryBechtelBlue"
                android:textColor="@color/material_button_text_selector"
                android:text="@string/work_package_drawer_apply_filters"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/button_white_color_states"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/wpd_small_margin"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnResetFilters"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/wpfd_bottom_buttons_margin_top"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Been at this for several hours.  What I've also tried:

1. Tried to do a scroll to the bottom of the NestedScrollView after checkbox/radiobutton selection.  This produces a noticeable jump in the scrolling as the recyclerview is scrolling FIRST to the view: android:id="@+id/bottomView", then jumps to the bottom.
2. Tried disabling the scrolling of the whole NestedScrollView before selection (in onCheckChangedListener), then resetting it after.

Also adding to the mystery:  I use the same layout for another drawer layout that also contains checkboxes and radio buttons, and this behavior is not present.  I even inherit from the recyclerview adapter in for both recyclers in the drawer layouts.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a so so bad practice using an scrolling element and `RecyclerView` on the same Activity. Surely you will always get mistakes

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to realize your problem without some video. I would recommend to avoid to use match_parent for your Recyclerview inside ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is a hack, as it seems the nested scroll view wanted to scroll when checking the checkboxes or radio buttons:

Added a 0dp height view at the bottom of my layout:

```
        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottomFocus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnApplyFilters"
            />
```

Then I added a scroll listener to the scrollview:

```
   binding.scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener {
            v: NestedScrollView?, scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int ->

        val wpfd_text_size_bottom_view_pixel = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.wpfd_text_size_bottom_view_pixel)
        if (oldScrollY - scrollY > wpfd_text_size_bottom_view_pixel) {
            binding.bottomFocus.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
            v?.scrollToBottom()
        }
    }
```

Where wpfd_text_size_bottom_view_pixel is the size of the bottom bar that the nested scrollview wanted to scroll.